# ¿Cómo verifico el status de mis clientes con sockets en java?

Tags: java, socket

<sub>No necesito código, solo necesito que me ayuden con la lógica</sub>

Estoy programando un control de ciber. Supongamos que tenemos este caso (en este es el que tengo la duda)

- Las computadoras clientes en cuanto encienden se bloquean por
  default.
- Mi computadora cliente 2 está trabajando y le quedan 15 min en tiempo, todas las demás clientes están bloqueadas.
- De pronto mi servidor se apaga, al encender quiero verificar el tiempo de todas las clientes y validar si alguna tiene tiempo (en
  este caso la número 2) y desbloquearlas.

Cómo hago para que el servidor verifique todo esto y me desbloqueé exactamente la máquina 2 porque esa es la que tiene tiempo?

Es acaso necesario que toda computadora cliente también actúe como servidor y escuche cuando el servidor esté ya arriba?

O cómo hago yo para recorrer todos mis clientes y verificar cuál está arriba y cuál no y de ahí validar si tiene tiempo o no para bloquearlo o desbloquearlo?

O acaso no funcionan así los Sockets?

Comment: Sí, necesitas un esquema server-server realmente. Cada cliente debe tener un solo socket servidor y la app que funciona como servidor principal se conectará al cliente mediante un socket cliente, solo así podrá enviarle los comandos que debe ejecutar

Comment: Justo a ti te estaba buscando, Luiggi xD Ayúdame con las dudas, porfa.

Comment: Entonces sí es así, las clientes van a tener que configurarse también como "servidor", es lo que quieres decir, vdd?

Comment: Sí, pero solo con 1 socket en modo servidor. Si no, no tiene manera de recibir notificaciones desde el servidor.

Comment: Pero eso me suena más a su es solo un cliente y solo un servidor. Pero si son muchos clientes y tengo que verificar el status de cada uno desde el servidor?

Comment: Mi pregunta principal es esa, si el servidor se me apagaba, al encenderse necesito recorrer todos mis clientes y revisar la información y el status de cada uno. ¿Cómo hago eso? Puedo obtener desde el server un arreglo de clientes y recorrerlos de uno por uno o cómo?

Comment: No confíes en la memoria. Guarda la información de los clientes en alguna parte, como en un archivo o en una pequeña bd que genere archivo como SQLite.

Comment: Y qué información de los clientes se necesita para conectarme a ellos desde el servidor o cómo le hago?
Este tema me trae loco desde la semana pasada, parece que el problema es que no entiendo cómo funcionan realmente los sockets y el cliente-servidor a este nivel. :c Estoy muy ansioso, creo que lo dejaré por la paz y lo retomaré en alguna otra ocasión

Comment: La dirección ip

Answer (score 0):

En cualquier caso necesitas que la máquina que actuará como servidor lleve un registro de sus clientes. Es decir tendrás una tabla en donde estará registrado cada cliente (su IP) y su estado actual.
De esta forma, la máquina que funciona como servidor hará su trabajo y, cuando sea el momento, le "dirá" a cada cliente lo que sea necesario en ese momento...(tiempo terminado, tiempo iniciado, o cualquier otra orden que deba cumplir la máquina cliente).
Ahora bien, es posible llevar a cabo esta tarea con Sockets de varias maneras.
Una opción que podemos llamar "server-server" (como te decían en uno de los comentarios) sería que los clientes se conecten al servidor, se registren en su tabla de clientes y abran un ServerSocket local para que el servidor se pueda conectar a ellos cada vez que lo necesite y les envíe las órdenes según correspondan.
Otra opción, que llamaríamos una arquitectura cliente-servidor tradicional, sería que los clientes se conecten al servidor y se registren en la tabla de clientes igual que antes pero, a diferencia del modelo anterior, que le vayan "preguntando" al servidor que hacer cada cierto periodo de tiempo (algunos segundos por ejemplo). Esta acción, el cliente la haría mediante el mismo Socket con el que inició la "charla" con el servidor, enviando una solicitud y luego leyendo la respuesta del servidor mediante los Input y Output Streams del Socket.
Como en todas las cosas de la vida, cada solución tiene sus ventajas y desventajas, tu decisión dependerá de que recursos de hardware y red prefieras priorizar entre otras cosas.

Comment: Excelente respuesta. En la primera opción que precisas en la que cada cliente genera su propio serversocket para que el servidor se conecte a ellas será necesario abrir tantas conexiones desde el server como direcciones ip guardadas en la base de datos, vdd?

Y en la segunda opción (que creo es la mejor en cuanto a recursos) todo estaría bien hasta que el servidor se cae y el socket de comunicación que se había creado se pierde.

Qué opinas?

Comment: En la segunda opción no necesito hacer un serversocket por cada cliente pues ellos estarían tratando de comunicarse con el servidor cada ciertos segundos. Eso parece una muy buena idea pero qué tantos recursos gastaría así en el cliente y en el server?

Comment: Además si es con el mismo socket, como te decía antes, se perdería si el server cae.

Comment: En el primer caso no necesariamente tendrás todas las conexiones abiertas a los clientes todo el tiempo, ya que el server se conectará a los clientes para mandarles una orden y luego cerrará la conexión hasta la próxima orden. Para que el servidor tenga todas las conexiones abiertas a la vez tendría que darse que todos los clientes necesiten justo en ese momento una orden, cosa que no pasará muy seguido.

Comment: En la segunda opción, como vos dijiste, cuando el servidor se cae se corta la comunicación si usas la misma instancia de Socket constantemente. En ese caso, en el próximo loop, el cliente se intentará conectar de nuevo y seguiria asi hasta encontrar al server levantado y de esa forma restaura la comunicación. Pero en esta opción el cliente puede usar una nueva instancia de Socket cada vez que haga un loop de pregunta, si al final de cuentas su estado lo tiene guardado el servidor de antemano.